# why my onclick function didn't work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i didn't understand why my onclick function didn't work. my function create run herself 2 time at the loading of the page but not when i click on the button

```js
   import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Topics } from '../api/topic.js';
import Topic from './Topic.jsx';

class AppCreate extends Component {



render(){

  return(
    <div className="container">
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="donnez un nom a votre Topic" className="topic"></input>
        <input type="button" value="Créer" onClick={this.create()}></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

  }
  create(e){
   {var test = document.getElementsByClassName("topic").value;
   console.log(test);}
  }
}



AppCreate.propTypes = {
topics: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};


export default createContainer(() => {
return {
  topics: Topics.find({}).fetch(),
};
}, AppCreate);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React onClick function fires on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work**

When you're passing `onClick={this.create()}` you're actually passing the return value of the function, and not the function it self. As a side effect, this will also cause that function to be called when a render occurs, not only when a user actually clicks.

**Solution**

You want to pass the function itself to be called, notice there are no parentheses `()`:

`onClick={this.create}`

**If you need to access the component instance in the click handle**

You'll also want to bind `this` (the instance of your component) inside your method, e.g. to access `this.state` you'll have to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) that value

`onClick={this.create.bind(this)}`

With this the execution inside create() will have a `this` value equal to the instance of your component, allowing you to access its attributes and methods like `this.props`, `this.state` and other methods you have defined on the component.

Comment: looks like he is missing bind too for the create function ...
this.create = this.create.bind(this)

Comment: If i use this on my function i have to use bind(this)? what is bind(this)?