# "Can only update a mounted or mounting component" upon typing into a form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Whenever I type something in the input field in `<Form />` I get the following error: `warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Form component.`. Refs don't work as well - whenever I submit an empty field the console says, that these are undefined. That doesn't seem to make any sense since I don't unmount my component. Do you have any ideas about what causes this error?

App.ts(AppContainer is from react-hot-loader library):

```
const render = (Component: any) => {
     ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <TodoList />
            </Provider>
        </AppContainer>,
     document.getElementById('root')
     )
};

render(TodoList); 

  if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./Containers/TodoList', () => { render(TodoList) })
}
```

TodoList.tsx(connected component)

```
@autobind
class TodoList extends React.Component<IProps, {}> implements ITodoList {

    public componentDidMount(): any {
        this.props.requestTodos();
    }

    handleClick(i: any) {
        this.props.requestDeleteTodo(i);
    }  

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const todoItems = this.props.todoItems.map((text, i) => {
            return <TodoItem deleteTodo={this.handleClick.bind(null,i)} key={i} text={text} />
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <Form postTodo={this.props.postTodo}/>
                <ul className='todo-list'>
                    {todoItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default connectComponent(['todoItems'], TodoList);
```

Form.tsx:

```
@autobind
class Form extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

    private todoInputField: HTMLInputElement; 
    private todoForm: HTMLFormElement;

    public state = {
        inputValue: ''
    }

    private handleTodoSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void =>  {
        e.preventDefault();
        var {inputValue} = this.state;
        this.props.postTodo(inputValue);
        this.todoForm.reset();
    }

    private update = (e: any): void => {
        var value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({inputValue: value});
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return(
            <form className={'todo-form'} ref={form => { this.todoForm = form; }} onSubmit={this.handleTodoSubmit} method="POST" action="">
                <input
                onChange={this.update}
                value={this.state.inputValue}
                ref={input => { this.todoInputField = input; }}
                placeholder="add todo!"/>
            </form>
        );
    }

};
```

Comment: Try changing your event handlers: `onChange={() => this.update}`, `onSubmit={() => this.handleTodoSubmit}` in `Form.tsx::render()` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to instantiate methods of the class in an ordinary way(without arrow functions) and it started working! It's pretty weird that the component doesn't work with arrow functions since I saw other people using syntax like this quite successfully.