# How to pass parameter to a function on onClick event in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
    class UserList extends Component{
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                list: [],
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.getList();
        }

        getList(){
            axios
            .get('/getList')
            .then(response => {
                if(response.data.status == 'success'){
                    this.setState({
                        list: response.data.list,
                    });
                    console.log(response);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log(error.response);
                  }
            });
        }




{/*I want to call this function with userid when remove button is pressed */}
        deleteUser(){ 

        }

        render(){
            if(!localStorage.getItem('name')){
                return( <Redirect to={'/login'} /> )
            }

            return (
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <table className="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#No</th>
                                    <th>#Name</th>
                                    <th>#Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>                                                        
                            {
                                this.state.list.map(function(item, i){
                                    return  <React.Fragment>
                                        <tr key={i}>
                                            <td>{item.id}</td>{/* **This is user id** */}
                                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button type="button" onClick="deleteUser(item.id)" className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </React.Fragment>  
                                })
                            } 
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default UserList;
```

I am new to ReactJS. I am trying to pass `userid` to function with `onClick` event to Remove button. But unable to send `userid` and it shows error. How can I do it. Can anybody help me with this. 
I am trying to pass `userid` to function with `onClick` event to Remove button. But unable to send `userid` and it shows error. How can I do it. Can anybody help me with this.
I am trying to pass `userid` to function with `onClick` event to Remove button. But unable to send `userid` and it shows error. How can I do it. Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React onClick function fires on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler is not bound. You need to declare it like this:

```
onClick={() => this.deleteUser(item.id)}
```

So change it to:

```
{this.state.list.map((item, i) => {
                return  <React.Fragment>
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{item.id}</td>{/* **This is user id** */}
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => this.deleteUser("asd")}
                            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                            >
                            Remove
                          </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </React.Fragment>  
            })}
```

And your handler:

```
deleteUser = (id) => { 
  console.log(id)
}
```

Comment: It shows error:- TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteUser' of undefined

Comment: I've updated the handler with an arrow function, try it. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-forest-5ot9p)

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function in ReactJS with:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => deleteUser(item.id)}>...</button>
```

The function call is an expression and hence you need to use `{}` instead of double quotes.

Another essential ingredient for this to work is the context in which it is called. Currently it is inside a `function`, like so:

```
.map(function(item, i) {

})
```

The function here [owns the usage](https://javascript.info/bind) of `this` inside it and hence `this.deleteUser` will not work. To get this to work, you need to convert `function` to an arrow function which [has no `this` binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

```
.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteUser(item.id)}>...</button>
  )
})
```