# Child component inside .map function display all children instances

Tags: reactjs

I am building a website that allows a user to create a job opening, assign to it different requirements and delete it.

I have two main components:

- `HRdashboard` is the parent component in which all the job openings are listed.
- `MyOpeningCard` is the card that contains information of a single job opening. It comes from the `.map` function in the parent component:

**HRdashboard**

```
function HRdashboard({changeAuthLoginHR}) {
const [HRuser, setHRuser] = React.useState([]);
const [openings, setOpenings] = React.useState([]);

useEffect( ()=> {

    let unmountedOpenings = false
    async function getAllOpenings(){
        let response = await  axios("http://www.localhost:3000/api/v1/openings");
        if(!unmountedOpenings)
            setOpenings(response.data)
    }

    let jwt = window.localStorage.getItem('jwt')
    let result = jwtDecode(jwt)
    setHRuser(result)
    changeAuthLoginHR()
    getAllOpenings()
    return () => {
        unmountedOpenings = true
    }
    }, [],
)


return(
    <div>
        <Container style={{marginTop: "50px"}}>
            <Row>
                    {openings.map(opening =>
                        <Col>
                            <MyOpeningCard key={opening.id} opening={opening} /> # Here is where the child is
                        </Col>
                    )}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    </div>
)

}
```

**MyOpeningCard**

```
function MyOpeningCard({opening}) {

    return(

        <div>
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem', marginTop: "15px"}}>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{opening.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Requirements: </Card.Subtitle>
                    <Card.Text>
                        {opening.requirements[0].requirements.map(requirement => <li>{requirement}</li>)}
                    </Card.Text>
                    <div>
                    <Card.Link href="#" onClick={console.log(opening.id)}>Click Here</Card.Link> # If I click here, it console.log all the IDs, not only this opening id.
                    </div>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )

}
```

**My question:**

If I click on `Click Here` in my child component, it triggers `console.log(opening.id)`.
I was expecting to see in console only the `opening.id` of the Job Opening I click. However, I see all the ids of the openings.
Why is it so?

Comment: Should be callback, i.e. `onClick={() => console.log(opening.id)}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React onClick function fires on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `onClick` prop is calling a function which immediately runs the same time your child component is rendered, without even clicking, for all the child components.

```
onClick={console.log(opening.id)}
```

So, when you use the `.map()` method, all of your `<MyOpeningCard />` components get rendered, each of them immediately calling `console.log()` again and again, hence you see all the `id`s logged in the console.

You should pass a callback, instead, to the `onClick` prop which will be executed only when a click happens.

Change it to

```
onClick={() => { console.log(opening.id) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses after a function name executes the function.
even-though you didn't mean to do that, that's why wrapping it with an additional Arrow Function is needed, it happens as:

`() => console.log('something')`, this Arrow Function is not going to be invoked until the click actually occurs.

while if you pass `console.log` this way -no parenthesses-, it'll be logging the whole `Event` only upon the Click event occurrence.