# React behavior triggers all buttons on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I'm generating a list of persons and 'delete buttons' via `map()` to be rendered in a React component (passing the mapped list through props and rendering inside a `<p>` tag).

When react first renders, it triggers all buttons`onClick()` and the buttons cease working.

Why this behavior happens, please?

```
  const deletePerson = (id) => {
    console.log(`deleting id: ${id}`)
  }

  const mappedPersons = persons.map(person => 
    <li key={person.name}>
      {`${person.name} - `}
      {`${person.phone} `}
      <button onClick={deletePerson(`${person.id}`)} value={person.id}>
        delete person
      </button>
    </li>
)
```

console:

```
deleting id: 1
deleting id: 2
deleting id: 3
deleting id: 4
deleting id: 5
deleting id: 6
deleting id: 7
deleting id: 8
```

Comment: `deletePerson` method should be placed in the `callback` function. Placing `deletePerson()` is function call.

Answer (score 2):

this answer gets it:
[React onClick function fires on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)

changing the button `onClick` to:

```
<button onClick={() => deletePerson(`${person.id}`)} value={person.id}>
        delete person
      </button>
```

makes map stop calling the function on render.