# what is likely the problem that my screen is not scrolling onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to have my screen move to the newly added elements position in my React/Ionic App but no matter what I try it doesn't work right.

I have tried using refs. I have tried using scrollTo(), ScrollIntoView - which with refs moved the screen at all at least, I am trying to use IonContent Scroll functions now but it wont budge.

My goal is to have my screen scroll to the new exercise when i click the button

this is my code

```
const AddWorkout: React.FC<Props & InjectedFormProps<{}, Props>> = (
  props: any
) => {
  const { pristine, submitting, handleSubmit } = props;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState("");
  const [openPicker, setOpenPicker] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <IonModal isOpen={props.show} animated backdropDismiss>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle>Add A New Workout</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent
          scrollEvents={true}
          onIonScrollStart={_e => {
            console.log(_e);
          }}
          onIonScroll={() => { }}
          onIonScrollEnd={() => { }}
        >
          <form className="edit-modal">
            <IonGrid className="ion-no-margin">
              <IonRow>
                <Field
                  name="name"
                  title="Name"
                  component={ReduxFormInput}
                />
              </IonRow>
              <IonRow>
                <Field
                  name="date"
                  title="Date"
                  type="date"
                  values={new Date().toISOString()}
                  component={ReduxFormDateTime}
                />
              </IonRow>
              <IonRow>
                <Field
                  name="duration"
                  title="Duration"
                  duration={duration}
                  setDuration={setDuration}
                  openPicker={openPicker}
                  setOpenPicker={setOpenPicker}
                  component={ReduxDurationInput}
                />
              </IonRow>
              <FieldArray name="exercises" component={renderExercises} />
            </IonGrid>
          </form>
        </IonContent>
        <IonFooter>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              <IonButton expand="block" fill="clear" onClick={props.onCancel}>
                Cancel
              </IonButton>
            </IonCol>
            <IonCol>
              <IonButton
                expand="block"
                color="success"
                type="submit"
                onClick={handleSubmit(submitForm)}
                disabled={submitting || pristine}
              >
                Add Workout
              </IonButton>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
        </IonFooter>
      </IonModal>
    </>
  );
};

const renderExercises = (props: WrappedFieldArrayProps<{}>) => {
  const { fields } = props;
  const { error, submitFailed } = props.meta;

  const groupIdx: Array<any> = fields.getAll()

  const moveExerciseUp = (from: number, to: number) => {
    if (from !== 0) {
      fields.move(from, to);
    }
  };

  const moveExerciseDown = (from: number, to: number) => {
    if (from !== fields.length - 1) {
      fields.move(from, to);
    }
  };

  const onMovePosition = (from: number, pos: number) => {
    if (pos > 0 && pos <= fields.length) {
      let breakOutOfLoop = false
      groupIdx.forEach((field, idx) => {
        // if one of the items has the correct group number,
        // assign the position to move to to that position
        if (field.group === pos && !breakOutOfLoop) {
          fields.move(from, idx)
          breakOutOfLoop = true
        }
        if (idx + 1 < fields.length && field.group > groupIdx[idx + 1].group) {
          fields.swap(idx, idx + 1)
        }
      })
    }
  }

  // THIS IS WHERE MY CODE IS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  const gotoButton = () => {
    let y = document.getElementById("exerciseScroll")!.offsetTop;
    let content = document.querySelector("ion-content");
    content?.scrollToPoint(0, y);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <IonRow className="sticky-button">
        <IonCol>
          <IonButton
            type="button"
            expand="full"
            onClick={() => {
              fields.push({ group: fields.length + 1 })
              gotoButton()
            }}
          >
            Add Exercise
          </IonButton>
        </IonCol>
      </IonRow>
      <IonRow>
        <IonCol>
          {fields.map((exercise, idx) => {
            return (
              <div key={idx} className="ion-text-center" style={{ border: "1px solid black", borderRadius: "5px" }}>
                <IonRow className="ion-margin-vertical">
                  <IonCol size="6" className="ion-no-padding ion-margin-vertical ion-text-right">
                    <h4 style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                      Exercise Group #
                    </h4>
                  </IonCol>
                  <Field
                    name={`${exercise}.group`}
                    component={ReduxFormGroupInput}
                    position={idx}
                    parse={(value: string) => parseInt(value, 10)}
                    normalize={
                      (value: any, previousValue: any, allValues: any) => {
                        if (value < 0 || value > fields.length || isNaN(value)) {
                          return previousValue
                        }
                        if (idx > 0 && allValues.exercises[idx - 1].group - 1 < allValues.exercises[idx].group) {
                          let i = idx + 1;
                          for (i; i < fields.length; i++) {
                            if (groupIdx[i].group === groupIdx[idx].group) {
                              allValues.exercises[i].group--
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        return allValues.exercises[idx].group
                      }
                    }
                    change={onMovePosition}
                    className="ion-no-padding ion-float-left ion-text-center"
                  />
                  <IonCol>
                    <small style={{ color: "gray" }}>(Change the group # to create supersets)</small>
                  </IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                <IonRow>
                  <div style={{ position: "relative", marginRight: 30 }}>
                    <IonButton
                      fill="clear"
                      size="small"
                      style={{ position: "absolute", top: 10, left: 0 }}
                      onClick={() => moveExerciseUp(idx, idx - 1)}
                    >
                      <IonIcon icon={arrowUp} slot="icon-only" />
                    </IonButton>
                    <IonButton
                      fill="clear"
                      size="small"
                      style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, left: 0 }}
                      onClick={() => moveExerciseDown(idx, idx + 1)}
                    >
                      <IonIcon icon={arrowDown} slot="icon-only" />
                    </IonButton>
                  </div>
                  <Field
                    name={`${exercise}.name`}
                    title="Exercise Name"
                    component={ReduxFormInput}
                  />
                </IonRow>
                <IonButton
                  onClick={() => fields.remove(idx)}
                  color="danger"
                  fill="clear"
                  size="small"
                >
                  REMOVE EXERCISE
                </IonButton>
                <FieldArray
                  name={`${exercise}.sets`}
                  props={null}
                  component={renderSets}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          {submitFailed && error && (
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</span>
          )}
        </IonCol>
      </IonRow>
      <div id="exerciseScroll" />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hello.  Maybe there is an additional `!` in your code above on this line `document.getElementById("exerciseScroll")!.offsetTop;` just before `.offsetTop`.  Is it intentional?

Comment: Yes that’s typescript syntax to let it know it’s not undefined or null

Answer (score 1):

It's the way you're calling gotoButton in your onClick event. It's evaluating gotoButton before your component is done rendering. See this answer for an example of this: [React onClick function fires on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)

To avoid this, you could run fields.push({ group: fields.length + 1 }) inside your gotoButton function and passing gotoButton like this 'onClick={gotoButton}'.

Comment: That didnt seem to fix it. i changed it exactly to what you said but nothing appears to have changed. Is it possible this can be a css problem?