# Passing an onClick function from parent to child, automatically calls it on page render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I passed this function to a child component of mine:

```
const mopen_editquestion = (question) =>  {
    setMShowEditQuestion(true)
    console.log(question)
}
```

through this:

```
<QuestionT click={mopen_editquestion} question={question} />
```

And in my child component, I call it here:

```
<img className="hover-hand" onClick={props.click(props.question)} src={edit_icon} alt="settings" width="30vh"/>
```

When the page renders, the modal (called from `setMShowEditQuestion(true)`) is already opened, and the console log is already flooded from the `console.log(question)` even if I haven't clicked anything on it yet. It seems its calling the function on render?

Any advices for this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing to `onClick={()=>props.click(props.question)}`

what is happening now is that you already executed that function, instead of tossing it into the `onClick` attribute.

Check this post ([React onClick function fires on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)) for more information.