# Can I use a ternary operator inside of an image tag?

Tags: reactjs, image, conditional-operator

I'm trying to use a ternary operator inside an image tag to toggle between two sets of gifs.  It isn't working.  Is my syntax messed up, or can I just not do this?  Any suggestions? (code below)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Artist = ({currentArtist}) => {
    const ghostify = () => {
       if(isGhost) {
            setIsGhost(!isGhost)
        } 
    }

    //state
    const [isGhost, setIsGhost] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className="artist">
            <img src={isGhost ? currentArtist.vid : currentArtist.ghostVid} alt= 
                {currentArtist.name} />
            <h2>{currentArtist.name}</h2>
            <h3>{currentArtist.title}</h3>
            <button onClick={ghostify()}>Ghostify</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Artist
```

Comment: Could you also add the Error you're getting?

Comment: your onclick should be `onClick={ghostify}`, besides that the rest looks fine

Comment: I'm not getting ant error messages.  It just isn't toggling the gifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by off what I'm seeing because there is no error in your question and per memory the `onClick`:

```js
<button onClick={ghostify()}>Ghostify</button>
```

will always fire (Learned from "[React onClick function fires on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846682/react-onclick-function-fires-on-render)") so it should be:

```
<button onClick={() => ghostify}>Ghostify</button>
```

A couple of suggestions. I always prefer to declare my `useState` and `useEffect` and I want to say that I [read it was advised](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

I dont think you need to check the condition of the function so:

```
const ghostify = () => {
    if(isGhost) {
        setIsGhost(!isGhost)
    } 
}
```

would be:

```
const ghostify = () => setIsGhost(!isGhost)
```

I prefer to de-structure and when you dont always know if you'll have a `name` or `title` I like to set a default value or condition the render. I'd change your component to condition for `name` and `title`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Artist = ({ currentArtist }) => {
  const [isGhost, setIsGhost] = useState(false)
  const ghostify = () => setIsGhost(!isGhost)
  const { vid, ghostVid, name, title } = currentArtist

  return (
    <div className='artist'>
      <img src={isGhost ? vid : ghostVid} alt={name} />
      {name && <h2>{name}</h2>}
      {title && <h3>{title}</h3>}
      <button onClick={() => ghostify}>Ghostify</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Artist
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help.  It's working great now.  All of the extra tips are very appreciated.